# Why can my fields not be bound in a T-SQL join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 1 THEN 'Condition1'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 2 THEN 'Condition2'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 3 THEN 'Condition3'
    ELSE ' '
    END
    AS Recommendation,
    table2.Notes,
    table3.ItemDescription AS Item,
    table4.Description AS Concern
FROM Job
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON Job.JobId = table2.JobId
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.table2Id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.table3Id = table3.table3Id
LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table4.table4Id = customName.table4Id
WHERE Job.JobId = @JobId AND table1.Condition = 3
```

This is for a telerik report, and the `JobId` variable will be input with an actual job id. `table2` holds the `JobId`, as well as the `table1` id. I am trying to get the `table4.Description`, but everytime I get the errors:

```
The multi-part identifier table4.table4Id could not be bound. 
The multi-part identifier table4.Description could not be bound.
```

At this point I don't know what to try from here. Any help would be appreciated! I will gladly add any more information as possible to try to figure out this issue

Comment: Does your table `table4` reallt have a column called `table4id`? The error says it does not. Also `LEFT JOIN table1 customNam`? Why didn't you call `table1` `customName` is the first place?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, it does have that column. I have to use `customName`(not its actual name) because I was getting an error saying I needed to use correlation names on the second join for `table1`

Comment: I don't see any `JOIN` to `table4`.  How do you expect to get `table4.Description` if it's not even `JOIN` the table???

Comment: @Eric table4 is apart of the last join.

Comment: Nope, I don't see it.  The only tables I see are `Job`, `table2`, `table3`, `customName`.

Comment: @Eric `customName` is `table4`... its a correlation name

Comment: Is there an outer query?

Comment: @Eric what would the outer query be for?

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation name"?

Comment: @eric https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/correlation-names?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You say "`customName` is `table4`... its a correlation name", but that's not what your query text as shown in the question says. The query in the question text says `LEFT JOIN table1 customName`, so at the moment `customName` is `table1`. If you want to mention `table4` in the `SELECT ` list , or indeed in an `ON` expression, you have to actually have *the table name `table4` itself* somewhere in the list of tables in the `FROM` clause. You _do not have this_ at the moment, in the query in the question text. This is what everyone has been trying to tell you...

Comment: Aside: You may want to look into using a _simple_, rather than _searched_, [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) expression: `case table1.Recommendation when 1 then 'Condition1' when 2 then ... else ' ' end`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used any alias `table4`; because of that, the compiler gives the error.

Comment: What are allies? I am confused by your answer

Comment: How would I use an alias in that statement?

Comment: Hi i meant you are missing table4 in above query just change table4 to table2 in  query LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table2.table2Id = customName.table2Id

Comment: I have table4 in my query. I am using correlation names, so `customName` is the same as `table4`

Comment: you cant used tables if you don't mentioned table or its alias in joins

Comment: @PrafulBangal what do you mean?

Comment: SELECT  CASE
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 1 THEN 'Condition1'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 2 THEN 'Condition2'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 3 THEN 'Condition3'
    ELSE ' '  END  AS Recommendation,
    table2.Notes,
    table3.ItemDescription AS Item,
    customName.Description AS Concern
FROM Job
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON Job.JobId = table2.JobId
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.table2Id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.table3Id = table3.table3Id
LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table1.table2Id = customName.table2Id
WHERE Job.JobId = @JobId AND table1.Condition = 3

Comment: If I do it that way I would not be able to use the table4.Description

Comment: but you haven't mentioned table4 any of the join. if you want used table4 as table then you must have join with other tables.

Comment: I don't understand why people keep saying that... I clearly have table4 as a part of my last join

Comment: you have job, table2, table1, table3 then table1 which is correlation names as customname but you missing table4 which you used only at conditions of joins.

Comment: does `LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table4.table4Id = customName.table4Id` not actually join table4?

Comment: yes it not identify as table, if you want to use table4 then replace last join  with this LEFT JOIN table4 ON table4.table4Id = table1.table4Id as you already have table1 so no need to used as alias again.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me. I could do this then, correct? `RIGHT JOIN table4  ON table1.table4Id = table4.table4Id`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are missing a `JOIN`. You just add your join condition.

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 1 THEN 'Condition1'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 2 THEN 'Condition2'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 3 THEN 'Condition3'
    ELSE ' '
    END
    AS Recommendation,
    table2.Notes,
    table3.ItemDescription AS Item,
    table4.Description AS Concern
FROM Job
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON Job.JobId = table2.JobId
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.table2Id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.table3Id = table3.table3Id
INNER JOIN table4 ON <I don't what what to join on>
LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table4.table4Id = customName.table4Id
WHERE Job.JobId = @JobId AND table1.Condition = 3
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than what I did, other than adding the ` INNER JOIN table4 ON <I don't what what to join on>` line. This doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Of course there's a difference.  In your case, you try to get a column that doesn't even exist.  How can you get a column of a table that is not in your result set?  In my query, `table4` is part of the result set, so you can get the column `table4.Description`

Comment: `table4` is clearly part of my results set: `LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table4.table4Id = customName.table4Id`. Unless I am missing something, I would think that would mean that table4 is apart of my results

Comment: This is the last time I'm going to say.  I clearly don't see `table4` in your result set.  Using proper table name like Order, OrderDetail, Item will be better instead of table1, table2.

Comment: I do use "proper table names", I am just not allowed to share the names of the tables. As per my comment above, would the line `LEFT JOIN table1 customName ON table4.table4Id = customName.table4Id` not include table4 in my results?

Comment: Back to my first question, where's that `table4` come from???  It's not in either your `FROM` or `JOIN`.  It's just magically appear.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at previous answers and conversations, I think the best solution is to just flip the join around.

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 1 THEN 'Condition1'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 2 THEN 'Condition2'
    WHEN table1.Recommendation = 3 THEN 'Condition3'
    ELSE ' '
    END
    AS Recommendation,
    table2.Notes,
    table3.ItemDescription AS Item,
    table4.Description AS Concern
FROM Job
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON Job.JobId = table2.JobId
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.table2Id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.table3Id = table3.table3Id
RIGHT JOIN table4 ON table1.table4Id = table4.table4Id
WHERE Job.JobId = @JobId AND table1.Condition = 3
```